# Rspec constant via inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, rspec, constants

I have a ruby app.

One class is:

```
module Transfer
  class Base
    (...)
    private

    def substract_commissions
      sender_account.commission INTER_BANK_COMMISSION
    end
end
```

Another one:

```
module Transfer
  class InterBank < Base
    INTER_BANK_COMMISSION = 5.00

    private

    (...)
  end
end
```

I am testing with Rspec the class Base.

At some point I need to check that the `sender_account` may receive a commission with an argument:

`expect(sender_account).to receive(:commission).with(the_constant)`

The problem is that the constant is defined on his "son" `InterBank`
ans as expected it throws this error:

```
 NameError:
       uninitialized constant Transfer::Base::INTER_BANK_COMMISSION
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what pattern did you end up using?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined `INTER_BANK_COMMISION` in `Base`, so you need to reference it through the class it was defined in. Since you're in the `Transfer` module, you should be able to use `InterBank::INTER_BANK_COMMISSION`, and you can always fully qualify it as `Transfer::InterBank::INTER_BANK_COMMISSION`.

---

That out of the way, you should take a closer look at your design. You're referencing a subclass's (`InterBank`'s) constant in the superclass (`Base`), which unnecessarily couples the superclass to its subclass. A subclass should strictly be a specialization of its superclass, and modifications like deleting the subclass should not require changes to the superclass - in this case, `INTER_BANK_COMMISSION` would vanish and nothing inheriting from `Base` would be able to `subtract_commission` anymore.

A clean way to avoid the dependency is to leave `Base#subtract_commissions` empty and then override it in `InterBank`:

```
class Base
  private

  def subtract_commission
    # No default commission
  end
end

class InterBank < Base
  INTER_BANK_COMMISSION = 5.00

  private

  def subtract_commission
    sender_account.commission INTER_BANK_COMMISSION
  end
end
```

This way, `Base` knows nothing about `InterBank` and has no commissions, and `InterBank` independently subtracts the commission that is specifically necessary to its type of transfer.

The commission subtracting behavior looks like it will be shared by many subclasses of `Base`, so you can hoist that back up and leave the subclasses needing only to declare their commissions:

```
class Base
  private

  def commission
    0
  end

  def subtract_commission
    sender_account.commission commission
  end
end

class InterBank < Base
  INTER_BANK_COMMISSION = 5.00

  private

  def commission
    INTER_BANK_COMMISSION
  end
end
```

Now you don't need to reimplement the subtraction in every subclass, each only  declares the amount of commission its type of transfer charges. New subclasses are easy to define and properly independent of one another.

You can even reference each class's constant directly if you want to, without the need for the `commission` method.

```
class Base
  COMMISSION = 0.00

  private

  def subtract_commission
    sender_account.commission self.class::COMMISSION
  end
end

class InterBank
  COMMISSION = 5.00
end
```

`self.class` resolves to `Base` or `InterBank`, and then each defines its own `COMMISSION`. This is nice, because now you can reference any commission the same way as just `<class>::COMMISSION`, instead of having the redundant `InterBank::INTER_BANK_COMMISSION` names.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I agree with everything [Kristján](https://stackoverflow.com/users/802618/kristj%C3%A1n) said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33713255/567863) with regards to refactoring your code, and I think you should consider what he has written in order to improve it.

Having said that, I believe the key to getting some passing tests with *the least amount of code changes* (can't emphasis this point enough) is in his last point: reference each class's constant directly by changing the line  `sender_account.commission INTER_BANK_COMMISSION` to
`sender_account.commission self.class::INTER_BANK_COMMISSION`

Here is are some specs that cover the parent and child class:

```
module Transfer
  class Base
    private

    def subtract_commissions
      sender_account.commission(self.class::INTER_BANK_COMMISSION)
    end
  end

  class InterBank < Base
    INTER_BANK_COMMISSION = 5.00
  end
end

module Transfer
  RSpec.describe Base do
    let(:transfer_base) { described_class.new }

    describe '#subtract_commissions' do
      # Substitute this test double out for whatever an actual
      # sender account looks like in your application
      let(:sender_account) { double('sender_account') }

      before do
        # The INTER_BANK_COMMISSION constant has not been defined
        # in Base, so to get the test to pass, it needs to be stubbed out
        stub_const('Transfer::Base::INTER_BANK_COMMISSION', 0.00)
        allow(transfer_base).to \
          receive(:sender_account).and_return(sender_account)
      end

      it 'sends a commission to the sender account' do
        expect(sender_account).to \
          receive(:commission).with(described_class::INTER_BANK_COMMISSION)
        transfer_base.send(:subtract_commissions)
      end
    end
  end

  RSpec.describe InterBank do
    let(:transfer_interbank) { described_class.new }

    describe '#subtract_commissions' do
      let(:sender_account) { double('sender_account') }

      before do
        allow(transfer_interbank).to \
          receive(:sender_account).and_return(sender_account)
      end

      it 'sends a commission to the sender account' do
        expect(sender_account).to \
          receive(:commission).with(described_class::INTER_BANK_COMMISSION)
        transfer_interbank.send(:subtract_commissions)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

- The specs above directly test `substract_commissions` which is a private method on the classes.  I'm assuming that in your app you have a public method that calls `substract_commissions`, and it is that method you should put under test
- The `sender_account` is a test double in the spec as I couldn't tell what kind of object it was from the information given, so you'll want to likely disregard that part in your own specs
- The spec on `Base` only passes because the `INTER_BANK_COMMISSION` constant is stubbed out.  If you ever actually use an instance of the `Base` class directly and you call the method that calls `subtract_commissions`, you'll get errors, so please consider re-visiting your design.